# Why is my cardano-node not working anymore?

Tags: cardano-node, node

My cardano-node is failing, and I'm not sure how to debug or fix it:

```
NodeToClientV_10    HardForkNodeToClientEnabled HardForkSpecificNodeToClientVersion2 (EraNodeToClientEnabled ByronNodeToClientVersion1 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion4 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion4 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion4 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion4 :* Nil)
[vvv-:cardano.node.ChainDB:Info:5] [2022-02-01 02:44:25.51 UTC] Opened imm db with immutable tip at 1ae2812fe7d76761e9d6f3733fcb8ee9c468040152ae8ad7f58d0527703e443f at slot 51967021 and chunk 2405
[vvv-:cardano.node.ChainDB:Info:5] [2022-02-01 02:44:33.05 UTC] Opened vol db
[vvv-:cardano.node.ChainDB:Info:5] [2022-02-01 02:45:25.71 UTC] Replaying ledger from snapshot DiskSnapshot {dsNumber = 51964788, dsSuffix = Nothing} at 8f134f487815d32650107fb04609ad1a7fbab47daaa55d27e6a4b4c3588c705f at slot 51964788
[vvv-:cardano.node.ChainDB:Info:5] [2022-02-01 02:45:26.22 UTC] Replayed block: slot SlotNo 51964807 of At (SlotNo 51967021)
[vvv-:cardano.node.ChainDB:Info:5] [2022-02-01 02:45:37.13 UTC] block replay progress (%) = 100.0
[vvv-:cardano.node.ChainDB:Info:5] [2022-02-01 02:45:38.79 UTC] before next, messages elided = 51964826
[vvv-:cardano.node.ChainDB:Info:5] [2022-02-01 02:45:38.79 UTC] Replayed block: slot SlotNo 51967021 of At (SlotNo 51967021)
[vvv-:cardano.node.ChainDB:Info:5] [2022-02-01 02:45:38.79 UTC] Opened lgr db
Killed
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like it was out of memory: [102938.126815] Out of memory: Killed process 28026 (cardano-node) total-vm:1074350476kB, anon-rss:7832444kB, file-rss:2160kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:15576kB oom_score_adj:0
[102938.346596] oom_reaper: reaped process 28026 (cardano-node), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Killed` probably means it was killed by the OOM (Out Of Memory) killer. If it was OOM killed, there will be a message in the `dmesg` output.

Running the `node` requires at least 8GB and you should have 4G of swap as well.

Comment: `journalctl -k` around that time stamp is what you'd run to see kernel logs of what was killed.